# Image zooming solutions?

Tags: ajax, flash, zooming

Got waist deep in a project that will involve presenting zoomable hi res catalog images.  Was assuming I would use Zoomify (Can be seen at their dot com which I am not linking to) and bought a license.

Found out too late that their product relies on user preparing every image into a large number of tiles using their windows exe.

This app will be running under Linux on a virtual machine where I have vm root and I need to automate anything beyond the staff selecting a nice large picture.

Any favorite apps for this? Advice?

// Edit:  currently reviewing ajax solutions for this problem.
http://www.downloadjavascripts.com/Zoom%20And%20Magnifiers.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out (of course) that several kind souls have had their shoulder to this wheel already and have an open source solution:

http://greengaloshes.cc/2007/05/zoomifyimage-ported-to-php/

Answer (score 2):

[Zoomify Entreprise](http://www.zoomify.com/enterprise.htm) seems to offer tools to automate the work using a server-side language.

> – Converter scripting examples -
>   including scripts written in ASP, ColdFusion, and PHP

Comment: Thanks for that Zed.  It made me realize I was not being as creative as I should.  a little Googling produced an open source solution to paying $300 more:  http://greengaloshes.cc/2007/05/zoomifyimage-ported-to-php/